# Trying to animate a carousel with Framer-motion motion.div

Tags: reactjs, css-animations, framer-motion

I am trying to animate a carousel transition with Framer-motion motion.div, I am doing some reading but haven't made much progress as this is my first time using animations. If anyone could point my in the right direction I would be very grateful! I basically have a piece of state linked to my pagination that sets the scroll direction on the animation to either "left" or "right", i really just need to figure out a way to set the enter and exit animation on my motion.div using this right or left from state. I could change the state to have any value really.

I guess what Im confused about, is i'm currently showing the cards in my table as a Stack of items, and when I paginate, the stack changes, the cards currently shown change to the next set in the data object. I suppose Im not understanding how to animate the entrance and exit of one div as its changing? Im continuing to read about animations but am in a real hurry to get this done.

heres what I put together:

```
  <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
          <motion.div animate={{ x: { ???? } }}
            style={{ position: 'absolute' }}>
              <HStack spacing={6}>
                {data.objectives.edges.map(e => (
                  <ObjectiveCard
                    objective={e.node}
                    key={e.node.id}
                    completeObjective={completeObjective}
                  />
                ))}
              </HStack>
          </motion.div> 
        </AnimatePresence>
```

Comment: Try checking this example for reference. It was provided in the documentation. [AnimatePresence example](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-image-gallery-pqvx3?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2FExample.tsx)

Comment: youre my hero! I was almost doing what they were suggesting... I was setting my key on the wrong component.